# Casperjs click won't open 'download csv' os window

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Current software stack:
Casperjs 1.1 beta,
Phantomjs 1.9.7,
Windows 8.1 64 bit,
Visual Studio 2013

I've been trying to use casperjs to automate a simple process. I want to navigate to the following url:

```
http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=TSLA&region=usa&culture=en-US
```

From there I want to simulate a click event on the `Export` button, found within the table header, and download the `.csv` file from the os popup window.

Thinking this would be relatively simple was foolish of me. Thus far I have been able to navigate to the page, confirm it is the correct page, use either a `CSS` or `Xpath Selector` to locate the proper element. Problem is when I use the `click` or `thenClick` methods the script runs with NO errors however the screen capture does not show a click event like a popup window etc.

I moved on to trying the `mouseEvent` method to simulate the click Export however this time the script runs but the output returns a warning from Phantom - `Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200)`.

Also of note is the `inspect element` value using Chrome within the aforementioned page:
`<a href="javascript:SRT_stocFund.Export()" class="rf_export"></a>`

I continued to dig into the page files and located the definition of the javascript export function:

```
SRT_stocFund.Export = function () {
    //return false;
    var params = this.GetPara();
    document.location = hostPath+"/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?" + params+"&denominatorView="+denominatorView+"&number="+number;
};
```

See my current code below. If necessary I can provide some excerpts from the cmd shell debug output.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,
        loadplugins: false,
    },
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'
});


phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
var utils = require('utils');
var fs = require('fs');
var cookies = JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies);
fs.write('cookies.txt', cookies, 644);

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

// which 3 statements; select from:
// 'income-statement/is'
// 'balance-sheet/bs'
// 'cash-flow/cf'

var statement = 'income-statement/is';
var stock_here = 'TSLA';

// morningstar url
var url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/' + statement + '/is.html?t=' + stock_here + '&region=usa&culture=en-US';

// open url
casper.start(url, function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    console.log('site load...');
    if (this.visible('#sfcontent > div.rf_ctlwrap > div.rf_ctl2_opt > div.exportButton > span > a')) {
        this.echo("This element selector expression is FOUND");
    } else {
        this.echo("This element selector expression is MISSING");
    }
}).viewport(1200, 1000);

casper.waitForSelector('#sfcontent > div.rf_ctlwrap > div.rf_ctl2_opt > div.exportButton > span > a', function () {
    casper.mouseEvent('click', '#sfcontent > div.rf_ctlwrap > div.rf_ctl2_opt > div.exportButton > span > a');
    casper.wait(1000);
    casper.capture('clicked.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use casperjs? You can just fetch the direct URL for the CSV, this seems to work as intended:

```
import urllib2
import csv
import StringIO

url = "http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:{}&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&reportType=is&period={}&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&rounding=3&view=raw&denominatorView=raw&number=3"

stock = "TSLA"
period = 12 #In months, 12 = annual, 3 = quarterly, etc.    

request = urllib2.urlopen(url.format(stock, period))

filename = request.info()['Content-Disposition'][21:-1]
data = request.read()

f = StringIO.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(f)

for row in reader:
    print row
```

For python 3.4:

```
import urllib.request
import io   
import csv

url = "http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:{}&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&reportType=is&period={}&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&rounding=3&view=raw&denominatorView=raw&number=3"

stock = "TSLA"
period = 12 #In months, 12 = annual, 3 = quarterly, etc.    

request = urllib.request.urlopen(url.format(stock, period))

filename = request.info()['Content-Disposition'][21:-1]
data = str(request.read())

f = io.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(f)

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Comment: I prefer a solution that automates this repetitive task. Unfortunately I don't see how your answer can be adapted for that purpose. I prefer to use Casperjs based on the detailed documentation and cosigns from other programmers more credible than I am.

Comment: You want this "From there I want to simulate a click event on the Export button, found within the table header, and download the .csv file from the os popup window.". The code I provided skips the first step and goes straight to the .csv download. My solution uses only the standard library, so some would call it more reputable than a third party library.

Comment: your solution is the same as physically clicking the link on the page and downloading the csv. b/c I see no way to generate that link for: 1. different stock tickers 2. different statements (there are 3) 3. annual or quarterly. Therefore it won't work in my case. If you have an alternative solution I'm all ears.

Comment: To change stock, you just change the stock variable. To get annual you just change the period GET variable in the URL, 12 is annual, 3 is quarterly etc. I don't see why this is not 100 times better than spinning up a headless browser with casperjs.

Comment: Not bad, throws an error `must be str, not bytes` but I can see the data. Can you please amend your solution to address how would you parse this output for use in a CSV or pandas dataframe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58648/discussion-between-bcr-and-scandinavian).